# Close iframe modal with button

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using the following to load an iframe from a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(d){
var%20modal=document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src','http://myurl.com/page.html?url=
'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&
page_title='+document.title);
modal.setAttribute('scrolling','no');
modal.className='modal';
document.body.appendChild(modal);
var c=document.createElement('link');
c.type='text/css';
c.rel='stylesheet';
c.href='//myurl.com/css/wl_iframe.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);
}(document));
```

and to close it I am trying:

```
<button onclick="parent.$.iframe.close();">X Close Window</button>
```

I've also tried:

```
<button onclick="modal.$.iframe.close();">X Close Window</button>
```

But they are not working, they do nothing.

I know I can use:

```
<a href="underneath url" target="_parent">X Close Window</a>
```

But this then causes a the browser to re-refresh the page they were looking at and also the user has to press the back button twice to get to the page before which is not ideal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should add some name or id to your iframe

```
javascript:(function(d){
var modal=document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src','http://myurl.com/page.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&page_title='+document.title);
modal.setAttribute('scrolling','no');

modal.setAttribute('name', 'my_modal_window');

modal.className='modal';
document.body.appendChild(modal);
var c=document.createElement('link');
c.type='text/css';
c.rel='stylesheet';
c.href='//myurl.com/css/wl_iframe.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);
}(document));
```

And then

```
<a href="#" onclick="var modals = document.getElementsByName('my_modal_window'), i = modals.length; while(i--){ modals[i].parentNode.removeChild(modals[i])}">X close window</a>
```

**EDIT**
 working solution, have just tested on stackoverflow inside Chrome JS console:

```
(function(d){
var modal=document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src','http://myurl.com/page.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&page_title='+document.title);
modal.setAttribute('scrolling','no');

modal.setAttribute('name', 'my_modal_window');

modal.className='modal';
document.body.appendChild(modal);
var c=document.createElement('link');
c.type='text/css';
c.rel='stylesheet';
c.href='/css/wl_iframe.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.onclick= function(){
   var modals = document.getElementsByName('my_modal_window'),i = modals.length;
   while (i--) {
      modals[i].parentNode.removeChild(modals[i]);
   }
};
a.innerHTML = 'Close Iframes';
document.body.appendChild(a);
}(document))
```

Comment: Still not working for me - created a fiddle using google to show http://jsfiddle.net/xaZ9A/

Comment: many thanks - but have you tried it? Try opening it several times, the close link replicates itself